# Need help to identify a PCB

Tags: pcb

Does anyone recognize where this is from? Manufacturer, model # etc. Found it hidden away in a cupboard, wonder if it's useful at all. Got a fuse, 5 relays, couple of LEDs(all soldiered ofc). Reverse image search didn't work and couldn't find anything on to help pinpoint more info

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Something to do with a garage opener perhaps

Comment: Are there any printed P/Ns, logos, or texts on the back side of the board?  System seems to have 4 isolated inputs.  An older style garage door opener sounds like a good guess, (manually controlled).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have a AC-DC power supply (transformer, diode bridge...), relays and inputs/outputs.

It seems to be designed to control stuff using relays (motor, two SOLenoids, a buzzer...) so it probably comes from some sort of machine which uses these actuators.

If the chip with the Korean label on top is a standard chip and not a programmed microcontroller, then sending standard digital levels into the input pins may allow you to control the relays and use this in one of your projects if you need a relay board.